# How To Create and Verify Blind RSA Signatures With Crypto++?

Tags: rsa, digital-signature, crypto++

I've read through the whitepapers and specifications relating to blind signatures which I've been able to come across, inclusive of the Wikipedia entries, but these tend to focus on the mathematical theory behind it.

Is there a concise practical implementation of RSA blind signatures within c++ using the Crypto++ library?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a concise practical implementation of RSA blind signatures within c++ using the Crypto++ library?

Yes. The Crypto++ wiki has a section on blind signatures for RSA at [Raw RSA | RSA Blind Signature](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA#RSA_Blind_Signature). Below is the code taken from the wiki.

Crypto++ lacks blind signature classes. The method below follows the basic algorithm as detailed at [Blind Signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature). However, it differs from Wikipedia by applying the `s(s'(x)) = x` cross-check. The cross-check was present in [Chaum's original paper](http://www.hit.bme.hu/~buttyan/courses/BMEVIHIM219/2009/Chaum.BlindSigForPayment.1982.PDF), but it is missing from the wiki article. A second difference from Chaum's paper and wikipedia is, the code below uses `H(m)` rather than `m`. That's due to [Rabin in 1979](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-212.pdf).

As far as we know there is no standard covering the signature scheme. The lack of standardization will surely cause interop problems. For example, the code below uses SHA256 to hash the message to be signed, while [RSA Blind Signature Scheme for golang](http://github.com/cryptoballot/rsablind) uses full domain hashing. Also see [Is there a standard padding/format for RSA Blind Signatures?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54085/10496) on Crypto.SE.

You may want to apply a padding function first per [Usability of padding scheme in blinded RSA signature?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12707/10496) or [RSA blind signatures in practice](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5626/10496).

---

```cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "integer.h"
#include "nbtheory.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "rsa.h"
#include "sha.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::runtime_error;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Bob artificially small key pair
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    RSA::PrivateKey privKey;

    privKey.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(prng, 64);
    RSA::PublicKey pubKey(privKey);

    // Convenience
    const Integer& n = pubKey.GetModulus();
    const Integer& e = pubKey.GetPublicExponent();
    const Integer& d = privKey.GetPrivateExponent();

    // Print params
    cout << "Pub mod: " << std::hex << pubKey.GetModulus() << endl;
    cout << "Pub exp: " << std::hex << e << endl;
    cout << "Priv mod: " << std::hex << privKey.GetModulus() << endl;
    cout << "Priv exp: " << std::hex << d << endl;

    // For sizing the hashed message buffer. This should be SHA256 size.
    const size_t SIG_SIZE = UnsignedMin(SHA256::BLOCKSIZE, n.ByteCount());

    // Scratch
    SecByteBlock buff1, buff2, buff3;

    // Alice original message to be signed by Bob
    SecByteBlock orig((const byte*)"secret", 6);
    Integer m(orig.data(), orig.size());
    cout << "Message: " << std::hex << m << endl;

    // Hash message per Rabin (1979)
    buff1.resize(SIG_SIZE);
    SHA256 hash1;
    hash1.CalculateTruncatedDigest(buff1, buff1.size(), orig, orig.size());

    // H(m) as Integer
    Integer hm(buff1.data(), buff1.size());
    cout << "H(m): " << std::hex << hm << endl;

    // Alice blinding
    Integer r;
    do {
        r.Randomize(prng, Integer::One(), n - Integer::One());
    } while (!RelativelyPrime(r, n));

    // Blinding factor
    Integer b = a_exp_b_mod_c(r, e, n);
    cout << "Random: " << std::hex << b << endl;

    // Alice blinded message
    Integer mm = a_times_b_mod_c(hm, b, n);
    cout << "Blind msg: " << std::hex << mm << endl;

    // Bob sign
    Integer ss = privKey.CalculateInverse(prng, mm);
    cout << "Blind sign: " << ss << endl;

    // Alice checks s(s'(x)) = x. This is from Chaum's paper
    Integer c = pubKey.ApplyFunction(ss);
    cout << "Check sign: " << c << endl;
    if (c != mm)
        throw runtime_error("Alice cross-check failed");

    // Alice remove blinding
    Integer s = a_times_b_mod_c(ss, r.InverseMod(n), n);
    cout << "Unblind sign: " << s << endl;

    // Eve verifies
    Integer v = pubKey.ApplyFunction(s);    
    cout << "Verify: " << std::hex << v << endl;

    // Convert to a string
    size_t req = v.MinEncodedSize();
    buff2.resize(req);
    v.Encode(&buff2[0], buff2.size());

    // Hash message per Rabin (1979)
    buff3.resize(SIG_SIZE);
    SHA256 hash2;
    hash2.CalculateTruncatedDigest(buff3, buff3.size(), orig, orig.size());

    // Constant time compare
    bool equal = buff2.size() == buff3.size() && VerifyBufsEqual(
        buff2.data(), buff3.data(), buff3.size());

    if (!equal)
        throw runtime_error("Eve verified failed");

    cout << "Verified signature" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result of building and running the program:

```
$ g++ blind.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o blind.exe
$ ./blind.exe
Pub mod: b55dc5e79993680fh
Pub exp: 11h
Priv mod: b55dc5e79993680fh
Priv exp: 1b4fc70ff2e97f1h
Message: 736563726574h
H(m): 2bb80d537b1da3e3h
Random: 72dd6819f0fc5e5fh
Blinded msg: 27a2e2e5e6f4fbfh
Blind sign: 84e7039495bf0570h
Check sign: 27a2e2e5e6f4fbfh
Unblind sign: 61054203e843f380h
Verify: 2bb80d537b1da3e3h
Verified signature
```